# Hovering for element when inspecting

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there a away to get the element `input#fakebox-input` and locate it. I was thinking using By.cssSelector or By.xpath, but I don't know how I can include `input#fakebox-input`

[image: search element]

Answer (score 0):

Please give more details when asking questions, not sure what is the ask here ?

If you want help creating xpath or CSS may be show the developer console(f12), anyway , if I go to google and inspect the search, there is an input of a class, based on that, this xpath works, so if you have something similar, replace glFYF gsfi with your class name --

//input[contains(@class,'gLFyf gsfi')]